# How to enable firewall on Centos 7?

Tags: firewall, centos7

My firewall is currently inactive.

```
# systemctl status firewalld
firewalld.service
    Loaded: masked (/dev/null)
    Active: inactive (dead)
```

I used the following command to enable the firewall

```
$systemctl unmask firewalld
```

but I got this error

```
# systemctl unmask firewalld
Failed to issue method call: Access denied
```

Please advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is offtopic and should be submitted on another StackExchange site such as [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
```

But before you should install `firewalld`. You can use `yum` for that:

```
sudo yum install firewalld
```

Comment: Yeah I actually tried that too but didn't seem to work.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl restart firewalld
Failed to issue method call: Unit firewalld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl enable firewalld
Failed to issue method call: Access denied

Comment: Why do you accept an answer if it didn't work for you? (= Unfortunately, I'm not advanced linux user so I can't help you much.

Comment: I didn't know that means accepting. It was probably by mistake. Its my first time using this.

Comment: Try `sudo yum install firewalld`

Comment: So it is installed and you can't start it and enable?

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
systemctl unmask firewalld
```

> return: Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/firewalld.service.

After that, you can:

```
systemctl restart firewalld
```